# subtract the height/width of an object so it stays in the box when randomly placed?

Tags: javascript, height, width

My function works, but since the axes start at the top left the "X" the corner can start in the box but the rest of it is outside of my border.

How do I subtract the height and width of X so that the whole thing stays in the box with JavaScript? TIA!

```
putAnXBtn.onclick = function(){
    var theBox = document.getElementById("putAnX");
    var width = theBox.clientWidth;
    var height = theBox.clientHeight;

    var yPosition = Math.random()*height
    var xPosition = Math.random()*width;

    var theXElement = document.getElementById("theX");
    theXElement.innerHTML="X";
    theXElement.style.top = parseInt(yPosition)+'px';
    theXElement.style.left = parseInt(xPosition)+'px';

}
```

Comment: To be able to use the styles top and left, you need to declare position:absolute or position:relative. Do you have that in your CSS?

Comment: You already know how to get the width and height of an element with `clientWidth` etc. now all you have to do is get that from `theXElement` and subtract

Comment: Yes, `position:relative` is in my css. Is this the subtraction you are talking about `var width = theBox.clientWidth - theXElement.clientWidth`. Probably not bc it's not working for me